# How to get part of string in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to get part of string from a file and write it into a variable using win CMD, but the file have a few strings, and I need only part of the third string. For example, file "myfile.txt" contain next strings:

```
package:com.test0.android    
package:com.test1.android    
package:com.test2.android
package:com.test3.android
```

And I need to write only "com.test2.android" in to a variable, but I can't find solution how to do this. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "myfile.txt" ^| findstr "^\[3\]" ') do set "variable=%%b"
echo "%variable%"
```

Comment: This works ! Thanks dude. I was really stucked with this issue.

Comment: Change the `delims=]` to `delims=:` and it will remove the `package:` too

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. But give it a try

```
set str=package:com.test0.android
set str=%str:package:=%
```